# How to write : someone who don't or doesn't?

Tags: meaning, grammar, american-english

Please help me to understand.
My full sentence is

> "... as someone who **don't/ doesn't** only love his...".

I have already tried them both and both sounds right.

Answer (score 1):

Don't (do not) is the plural form,  doesn't (does not) is the singular. She does, he doesn't, they do, they don't.

And, especially relevant to the question, someone does and someone doesn't.

Comment: And, especially relevant to the question, *someone* ***does*** and *someone* ***doesn't***.

Comment: But "I do" and "you do"  are both (usually) singular.

Answer (score 0):

-he/she/it doesn’t (does not).... example: “she doesn’t work outside the home after having her twins”
-we/i/ they/you/ you all/ you guys don’t (do not).... example: “they don’t know how many hours we are working today.”